# Jews vs gentiles: disputes

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles, jewish-books, sources-mekorot

Recently I got a pleasureful reading of the [Ramban's dispute](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/haramban-2.htm).

I think it a great source for "דע מה להשיב" (know what to answer to heretics).

I'm sure there were similar disputes by other great Rabbis like Ramban in different times. Can anyone direct me to some of them?

Comment: help with tagging is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting, my brother told me once that there is a Rav or a source in a Sefer that says "Da Mah Shetasiv, aval Al Tashiv"

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's usually called a disputation, not a dispute.

Comment: Very doubtful that the modern day missionary or apikores would ask you a question like those disputed in the medieval disputations. A more practical "*da mah l'hashiv*" is probably something more like [this](http://jewsforjudaism.org/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=447&func=select&id=2).

Comment: @jake indeed great source (I viewed the Russian version). thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here (Hebrew)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/vikuhim.htm)

This is an excerpt from [אוצר ויכוחים](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D) -(a collection of arguments), a book published in the 20's on this very topic. It has polemics from over many centuries from figures ranging from Radak to the Chasdei Kreskas to Mos[es/he] Mendelsohn.

Comment: fun story. I just realized your original link is actually part of that source. Would have been nice of daat to link back to the original page on the individual articles :) .

Answer (score 4):

The Gemara itself has a famous account of Rabbi Yehoshua against the elders of Athens (Gemara Bechoros 8b). See the Marsha on the gemara to get a better understanding and for further reading "The Juggler and the King(a book on aggada based off the Gra)" is a great book on this topic.